# Jquery - Jscrollpane is stealing my focus()

Tags: jquery, focus, jscrollpane

is it possible to deactivate the autofocus() function in the jscrollpane plugin?

I set the focus on a  but i didn't works. You can see the cursor for 1 second in the textfield (i think the jscrollpane put it away).

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rY9zD/  if you open the page it works, but if you press the jsfiddle RUN button ist doesnt work. Strange ...

Comment: Same problem here. Jscrollpane was implemented by an outsourcer for our project and I can't set focus on form elements inside it. The focus is set correctly but then removed by Jscrollpane.